# Getting WebRTC performance indication

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

We've developed a professional WebRTC application and are trying to give users an indication of how many streams their PC can handle (2-7). Is there an easy way of figuring this out (in browser or with a separate application)?

It's a conference application we offer to users browsing with Chrome.

Another question, if you work with for example 7 streams, are they divided over the different CPU cores? Or is the whole WebRTC deal included in the process for that browser tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC makes extensive use of threads, so it can utilize more than one core especially in multi-party conferences.

The simplest way to check is to make calls to yourself (each one = 2 calls in a mesh conference).  If it's an MCU-style conference (likely with 7 participants), you need to simulate a one-way call (so you're doing one encode), plus decode N additional VP8 streams at "appropriate" resolutions.

This is complicated by Firefox, for example, using content analysis to selectively reduce resolution and/or frame rate of sent-video depending on load and outgoing bandwidth.  However, for your case, it's more one of reception.

The short answer, though, is that it's hard to be sure, and will depend on the other senders too.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Last thing I was wondering was if WebRTC makes use of the GPU. We're trying to get a good view of the needed components for a stable system and I find it hard to find any good information in the highly technical documentation provided by the WebRTC consortium.

Comment: webrtc per se doesn't use the GPU - though applications using it may well; the browser's compositor and drawing routines may; and if any platform/OS/hardware codec is used it could use a GPU - though few/none currently use HW codecs, more are coming - but more likely it would use a dedicated HW block.